# Multiple IF statements in Excel not working

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I would like to set a multiple IF statement for my formula.
The reason behind it is, that I need to switch off the values (mark them as N/A and NA) which are equal to the other certain values as follows:

LP372/24/60+1=($NO372-720)/24/60+1 => mark them as N/A - the values, which don't happen during the midnight

and

LP372/24/60+1=$NO372/24/60+1 => mark them as NA - the values, that don't happen during the midday

The problem is, that I can't keep them under one IF statement, because I need the division.

So far I used only one IF statement (the nested one), which looks as follows:

```
=IF(OR((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1), OR((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1))),"N/A",LP372/24/60+1).
```

The value of NO372 corresponds to the rough time of the local midday. Substracting the 720 we are getting the rough midday for this location, knowing that the single day counts 24 hours x 60mins = 1440mins.

The formula above gives a nice result, but without the division between midday and midnight, which I am talking about.

[image]

Following my older query about the similar issue:

[Double nested IF statement formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341027/double-nested-if-statement-formula-in-excel)

I tried to solve it like this:

```
=IF(COUNTA(E1116:E1481),IF(OR((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1),OR((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1))),"N/A",LP372/24/60+1),"NA")
```

where the range E1116:E1481 corresponds to the whole year period (1.01 - 31.12).
Unfortunately I got nothing, similarity to this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(E1116:BC1116),IF(OR((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1),OR((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1))),"N/A",LQ510/24/60+1),"NA"),
```

where the E:1116:BC1116 range correspond to the all columns - circumstances as occur on January 1.
This formula was still not correct.

I found [something on the web](http://blog.udemy.com/multiple-if-statements-in-excel/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=DSA_Catchall_la.EN_cc.ROW&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_88010211481_._ad_437497337004_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-48101304659_._li_20856_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpNr4BRDYARIsAADIx9woAJ0yErWTchugX38QwimNWb16dOw69AB32TgqNrQQCbuZ862al8saAgW_EALw_wcB) about the multiple IF statements:

which led me to the following formula

```
=IF((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1);"N/A";IF((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1);"NA")LP372/24/60+1)
```

Unfortunately again not correct.

The last attempt was an answer provided here:

[Multiple IF statements in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568623/multiple-if-statements-in-excel)

on which basis I built up another formula

```
=IF((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1),"N/A",LP372/24/60+1,IF((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1),"NA"))
```

this time Excel said, that I've entered too many arguments.

Is there a way to set up multiple IF statements?
I need to:

- make the values equal to midnight as N/A,
- make the values equal to midday as NA
- keep the other values as they stand

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are wanting to do, but if all you want to do is check a time value in a cell and mark a different cell as either "N/A" or the other value based off of if the time is midnight or noon, why can't you just do something like this: `=IF(OR(HOUR(B19)=12,HOUR(B19)=0),"N/A",B19)` ? this checks the hour of the cell (in this case B19) and if the hour is 0 or 12 (midnight or noon) you get `N/A`, else you get the value of the cell.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible that you are getting `FALSE` if you are copying and pasting my formula exactly into your sheet. If you are trying to use my formula as part of another formula that could result in you getting `FALSE`. How are you trying to implement my formula? can you post the exact final version of the formula you are using as well as the value in the cell you are examining?

Comment: =IF((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1),"N/A",IF((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1),"NO"))
Thhis is exactly what I am writing.
Instead of timevalues I am getting FALSE.
Maybe shall I do sth like this:
=IF((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1),"N/A",IF((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1),"NO"),LP372/24/60+1)
?

Comment: the reason you are getting false is because the last `IF` statement in the formula in the last comment does not have the final value in it. if the formula works other than just that here is the version that points out where to put the reference to your cell you want the timestamp from: `=IF((LP372/24/60+1)=(($NO372-720)/24/60+1),"N/A",IF((LP372/24/60+1)=($NO372/24/60+1),"NO","your timevalue cell reference goes here"))`

Comment: Perfect, that works. If for example, I will need another IF statement into it, I just will need the another ,IF(.....) in my code right?

Comment: yes. it's really easy to get lost when nesting `IF` statements, what I do when doing something like that is when adding a new `IF` statement, I type the structure out first like this: `IF( , , )` because each `IF` statement has 3 parts inside the parens: first is the condition you are checking against, second is what you want if that condition is true, third is what you want if the condition is not true. the reason you were getting `FALSE` is because you were leaving out the third part in the `IF` statement. so, because you didn't give that final value, it just displayed `FALSE`

Comment: This is such a milestone for me! Thanks for your help. I was flying blind searching a good explanation for multiple if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments, but I thought I would add an answer with an example of how to nest `IF` statements for anyone that found this question because they are having issues with nesting `IF` statements.

When you add an `IF` statement to a formula in excel, you have to keep in mind that `IF` statements have 3 parts separated with commas:

- The first value is the condition you are going to check
- The second value is the value you want returned if that condition is true
- The third value is the value you want returned if that condition is false

So here's an example that illustrates that:

```
=IF(condition to check, value if condition is true, value if condition is false)
```

Here is an example `IF` statement:

```
=IF(A1="Hello","World","something else")
```

If you are getting `FALSE` returned then your `IF` statement probably looks like this:

```
=IF(A1="Hello","World")
```

Notice that there are only 2 values inside this `IF` statement: the condition you are checking (`A1="Hello"`) and what you want displayed if that is true (`"World"`). `FALSE` would be displayed if the value in `A1` is something other than `Hello` because you haven't included the third value in the `IF` that defines what you want displayed if `A1` is not `Hello` (this value is listed as `something else` in the example above)

It's best to try and avoid nesting `IF` statements if you can because they can be hard to keep track of. I would suggest using `AND()` or `OR()` instead if you can. They are very similar to each other, you list multiple conditions within the parens separated by commas that you will be checking against, and both evaluate to either `True` or `False`. The only difference is that for `AND()` every condition within the parens needs to be true for it to evaluate to `True` where `OR()` only one of the conditions listed in the parens needs to be true for it to return `True`.

So, for example, if you wanted to display `World` if `A1` is `Hello` or `Hi` and you were to use nested `IF` statements it would look like this:

```
=IF(A1="Hello","World",IF(A1="Hi","World","something else"))
```

which in my opinion is really ugly. however, if you used `OR()` instead of nesting `IF` statements it would look like this:

```
=IF(OR(A1="Hello",A1="Hi"),"World","something else")
```

`AND()` works the same way, but instead of just needing one condition within the parens to be true to return `True` as `OR()` does, with `AND()` all conditions inside of the `AND()` need to be true to display your value instead of just one. here's an example `AND()`:

```
=IF(AND(A1="Hello",B1=""),"World","something else")
```

in this case "World" would be displayed only if `A1` is `Hello` AND `B1` is empty

for both `AND()` and `OR()` you can have more than just 2 values inside if you need to check for more than 2 conditions, you just need to separate them each with commas, like this:

```
AND(condition1, condition2, condition3, ....)

OR(condition1, condition2, condition3, .....)
```

but, if you have to use nested `IF` statements, the easiest way I've found is to type `IF( , , )` first thing to make sure you are allowing for all 3 values that need to be inside of the `IF` and you have the right amount of values inside the `IF`. If you are getting the message `You've entered too many arguments for this function` it is because you have entered more than 3 values inside your `IF`, like this:

```
=IF(A1="Hello","World","something else","this value is causing the issue")
```

so, to properly nest an `IF` in your formula, type `IF( , , )` first off where you want the `IF` statement to be in your formula and then just fill in the blanks, then you avoid entering too few values which results in `FALSE` being displayed if your condition is not true or `You've entered too many arguments for this function` because you entered more than 3 values in your `IF`

Hope this helps to understand `IF` statements and how to nest them properly.